# Add programatically a line break that will work on every version

Tags: excel

I'm writing an excel file using javascript (the language doesn't really matter) and came across the following issue...

I need to write a cell with line breaks. I have read that I just need to add `CHAR(10)` to my formula and voila! However, I will have to send this file to different people using different language versions of Excel. Therefore if a French opens the sheet, he will see an error because `CHAR(10)` should be `CAR(10)` same for other languages...

Is it possible to insert a line break programatically so it works on every versions?

Comment: Try `vbCrLf` in your code and check.

Comment: @PankajJaju Should it be a formula or inside a string?

Comment: Apologies. You should really use `vbLf`if you want line feed in Excel cell text. You can do it via VBA. For example, `Range("C1").Value = "Abc" & vbLf & "Pqr"`

Comment: @PankajJaju Unfortunately it doesn't work with my javascript library (https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)